# Error con imagen en netbeans 11.3

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, netbeans-11.3

Buenas chicos tengo este error al colocar una imagen en netbeans 11.3, incluso me sale el mismo error al intentar hacer con las opciones de netbeans, solo me da el problema al colocar una imagen, si no hay ni una sola imagen el codigo se ejecuta todo correctamente.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Librerias.ImagenFondo.<init>(ImagenFondo.java:19)
at Presentacion.MDIPrincipal.<init>(MDIPrincipal.java:22)
at Presentacion.MDIPrincipal$1.run(MDIPrincipal.java:118)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Este es mi cogido en clase principal:

```
  public MDIPrincipal() {
   initComponents();
    
   desktopPrincipal.setBorder(new ImagenFondo());
  }
```

Este es mi codigo de clase ImagenFondo:

```
  package Librerias;

  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Insets;
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import javax.swing.border.Border;


  public class ImagenFondo implements Border{
    public BufferedImage back;

    public ImagenFondo(){
      try {
        URL imagePath = new URL(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/bg.jpg").toString());
        back = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
      } catch (IOException ex) {            
      }
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      g.drawImage(back, (x + (width - back.getWidth())/2),(y + (height - back.getHeight())/2), null);
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
      return new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
      return false;
    }

  }
```

La linea 19 de ImagenFondo es:

```
URL imagePath = new URL(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/bg.jpg").toString());
```

Mis imagenes las tengo en un package Imagenes, y el MDIPrincipal en un package Presentación

Answer (score 0):

Este error es causado porque la ruta de la imagen no es correcta, como te comenta al utilizar el método `getResource` si el recurso no existe te lanzara `NullPointerException`, revisando la ruta me doy cuenta de que estas utilizando doble punto al inicio `../Imagenes/bg.jpg` el método  `getClass().getResource` inicia en al paquete donde está la clase que lo ejecuta y tienes que subir los niveles necesarios para llegar al recurso lo mejor es utilizar `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource`  porque de esta forma siembre inicias en la raiz de `src` el cambio a tu código seria el siguiente:

```
back = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Imagenes/bg.jpg"));
```

Para comprobar que funciona asegúrate que la estructura de carpeta físicas en tu proyecto donde esta la imagen sea la siguiente `src/Imagenes/bg.jpg`

Comment: Ya utilice getClassLoader y quitando los .. y me sigue mostrando el mismo error
Mi carpeta de imagenes esta en esta ruta: src\main\java

Comment: Mejor coloca la estructura de carpetas que tienes, porque cuando tienes `src\main\java` en `main` debes tener o colocar una carpeta `resources`